# Install NServiceBus.Host as service using WiX

Tags: wix, nservicebus

I'm creating an installer for our NServiceBus-based solution using WiX but I'm having trouble getting the host service to start after installing.

If I run the host's installer from the command line using `NServiceBus.Host.exe /install`, it installs fine and even starts successfully when I start the service.

However, when I create the service in WiX using a `ServiceInstall` element, it fails to start the service. I've tried starting the service in my installer using a `ServiceControl` element as well as post-install from the WIndows Services control panel.

The code I'm trying to use in WiX is:

```
<Component Id="NServiceBus.Host" Guid="PUT-GUID-HERE" Win64="yes">
  <File Id="NServiceBus.Host" KeyPath="yes"
      Source="$(var.[Project].TargetDir)NServiceBus.Host.exe" Checksum="yes" />
  <ServiceInstall Id="NServiceBus.Host.Install"
      Name="[Product].Host" DisplayName="[Product]" Type="ownProcess"
      Account="NT Authority\Network Service" Interactive="no" Start="auto"
      Vital="yes" ErrorControl="normal">
    <ServiceDependency Id="MSMQ" />
    <ServiceDependency Id="MSDTC" />
  </ServiceInstall>
  <ServiceControl Id="NServiceBus.Host.Control" Name="[Product].Host"
      Start="install" Stop="both" Remove="uninstall" Wait="yes" />
</Component>
```

I've used the same code in other projects to install and run services so I'm pretty sure the problem is related to NServiceBus's host. The service here also appears to install correctly but just fails to run.

Has anyone been able to install `NServiceBus.Host.exe` as a service using WiX? Or does anyone know if there's other steps that are happening when I run `NServiceBus.Host.exe /install` that I should replicate in my WiX installer?

I know I could create a `CustomAction` in WiX that runs `NServiceBus.Host.exe /install` but I'd rather avoid that if possible and install the service the correct (WiX) way. It also avoids me needing to consider the uninstall actions and sequencing.

**Edit:** For reference, this is how I create the queues with WiX's `MsmqExtension`:

```
<Component Id="NServiceBus.Host.Queue" Guid="PUT-GUID-HERE" Win64="yes">
  <msmq:MessageQueue Id="Queue1" Label="[Product] Host"
      PathName=".\private$\[Product].Host"
      Transactional="yes" PrivLevel="optional" />
  <msmq:MessageQueue Id="Queue2" Label="[Product] Host Retries"
      PathName=".\private$\[Product].Host.Retries"
      Transactional="yes" PrivLevel="optional" />
  <msmq:MessageQueue Id="Queue3" Label="[Product] Host Timeouts"
      PathName=".\private$\[Product].Host.Timeouts"
      Transactional="yes" PrivLevel="optional" />
  <msmq:MessageQueue Id="Queue4" Label="[Product] Host Timeouts Dispatcher" 
      PathName=".\private$\[Product].Host.TimeoutsDispatcher"
      Transactional="yes" PrivLevel="optional" />
</Component>
```

Comment: Can you provide the NSB logs & app.config?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there. You need to pass command-line arguments expected by `NServiceBus.Host.exe` to the `Arguments` attribute on the  `ServiceInstall` tag like

```
<ServiceInstall Id="NServiceBus.Host.Install"
     Name="[Product].Host" DisplayName="[Product]" Type="ownProcess"
     Account="NT Authority\Network Service" Interactive="no" Start="auto"
     Vital="yes" ErrorControl="normal"
     Arguments="-service NServiceBus.Production /serviceName:[Product].Host">
```

Install your service using the NSB host first, then peek all the command-line arguments from the Windows Service & put them into your WiX installer.

Edit:
If you don't want to run custom actions to get NSB to create queues and/or do other things in WiX @ installation time, you can achieve a similar effect by adding a custom NSB [profile](http://support.nservicebus.com/customer/portal/articles/859283-profiles-for-nservicebus-host) in your code, eg

```
namespace YourNamespace
{
    public class YourProfile : NServiceBus.IProfile { }

    public class YourProfileBehaviour : IHandleProfile<YourProfile>
    {    
        public void ProfileActivated()
        {
            WindowsInstallerRunner.RunInstallers = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Bear in mind, using the profile above will run NSB installer code (eg check and add queues if necessary) every time the service is restarted. I guess there are trade-offs both ways.

Comment: This will work, technically, but then queues won't get created, which is just one thing that the NServiceBus install process does for you.

Comment: Thanks. I'll look into this option and report back.

Comment: I'm not concerned about creating the queues because I can do that in WiX using the MsmqExtension. I've already got that part working.

Comment: Ok I gave that a try and the only thing I needed to change was your last arugument should read `-serviceName:[Product].Host`. Otherwise it seems to work. I was obviously missing the `-service` argument but it's actually the `-serviceName` that does the magic. (And the serviceName argument must exactly match the actual service name!)

Answer (score 1):

You should not try to replicate the NServiceBus host installer in WiX. There are lots of things that happen and these will change with every release so anything you would try would be very brittle.

Instead of a ServiceInstall element, you should simply execute the host with the correct command line handlers, and let NServiceBus take care of itself. I'm not really familiar with WiX but I assume there is some way to execute an arbitrary executable with command line args?

**To be clear**

Yes it is POSSIBLE to install an NServiceBus endpoint as a service with WiX. I'm saying you SHOULD not, not that you CAN not.

If you don't use the NServiceBus installer to install the endpoint, you will miss out on queue generation and other tasks that the NServiceBus Host invokes that WiX (without its knowledge of how NServiceBus operates) cannot.

Comment: Yes this is possible. However, it introduces a lot more complexities in managing when to run the executable to install and to uninstall. The concept of WiX is to describe the desired state of the system and let Windows make it so, instead of just running a sequential script where you have to handle all the conditional logic yourself. I'm just hoping there might be a way to install NServiceBus in the _correct_ WiX/Windows Installer way.

Comment: Rob Mensching's blog entry on avoiding custom actions: http://robmensching.com/blog/posts/2007/8/17/zataoca-custom-actions-are-generally-an-admission-of-failure

Comment: I have to disagree with this. A windows service is a windows service is a windows service. It has nothing to do with NSB. Doesn't NSB use topshelf to install itself as a service? If you were talking about the infrastructure installers then I'd agree. NSB prefers MSMQ & DTC configured in a specific way.

Comment: +1 I don't think this is bad advice by any means. `NServiceBusHost.exe` has specialist knowledge about how to install itself - it's sensible to use that knowledge. As @David Boike points out, if NServiceBusHost ever changes the way it installs, you get those changes automatically with zero maintenance overhead. Not saying I necessarily agree with this answer but there is some truth in it, and it doesn't deserve downvotes.

Comment: When NserviceBus installs, it runs some code to do startup actions. These typically include setting up all sorts of input queues, among other things. Yes it is possible to use WiX as shown in @ChrisBednarski's answer, by passing in the command line arguments that NSB expects when it runs, however you'd lose all those first-run actions.

Comment: I've taken the downvote off. There's some point to the comments added in the edit. To be pedantic, the question asks about installing NSB host as a windows service, nothing about creating queues.

Comment: Yeah I'm not worried about queues as I can create them with WiX's MsmqExtension. I've updated my question to show that code for anyone interested.